Movie about a group of child/teenager serial killers
I watched this movie a long time ago and I'm having a hard time trying to remember it.  It's a Hollywood movie. I watched it circa 2005 - 2010 probably. I don't remember many details of the movie. 
What I do remember is that it's about a detective that is currently investigating a group of serial killers, as the movie progresses he catches all of them and the leader of the group ends up being his son. All of these serial killers are kids or teenagers if I remember correctly and they have a color that identifies them. The color of his son, the group's leader, is white.

Do you have an approximate year that you saw this or when this might have been made?  Was the movie in English or another language?  Any idea on the country of origin for the movie?

@bluefeet it's a hollywood movie. I watched it circa 2005 - 2010 probably.

@user1461256 - So you watched it 2005-2010, was it in theaters? DVD? VHS? Details, man, details!

Heathers, perhaps?

You're looking for Horsemen from 2009 with Dennis Quaid.

Aidan Breslin is a bitter detective emotionally distanced from his two young sons following the untimely death of his devoted wife. While investigating a series of murders of rare violence, he discovers a terrifying link between a chain of murders and the Biblical prophecies concerning the Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse: War, Famine, Pestilence, and Death.

The 'Horsemen' are a group of killers, and near the end:

Aiden arrives later and enters [his son] Alex's room for the first time in three years. To his horror, everything in the room is white or painted white: the color of the Horseman Conquest, their leader.

Here's the trailer (slightly graphic):




Good work! Not sure my Google-Fu would've worked on this one...

Thanks. No Google, I just (faintly) remembered it, and not that fondly TBH.
